# PHP Form Errors only show once triggered

Tags: php, forms

I'm a bit of a PHP novice and need help figuring out how to make my form errors only show once the error is triggered.  For example: The form looks normal upon arriving at the page.  The user fills in the information but forgets to add an email and hits submit.  I want the email error to then show.  Below is the code I'm working with.

Side note: I have the fields set to retain inputted information upon hitting the submit button.

```
<?php 

            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
            $max_size = 34000000;
            $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
            $errors = array();

if (empty($email))
    $errors[] = "Please provide an email.";
if (empty($name))
    $errors[] = "Please provide your name.";
if (empty($filename))
    $errors[] = "Please provide a file.";
if ($size > $max_size)
    $errors[] = "Please choose a file under 30mb.";

if (sizeof($errors) > 0) {
    foreach($errors as $error)
    {
        printf("<li>%s</li>", $error);
    }
}
else {
    mkdir('../uploads/' . $email . '|' . $name, 0777, true) . '/';
    move_uploaded_file($file, '../uploads/' . '/'. $email . '|' . $name . '/' . $filename);
    header ('Location: ../');
    exit;
}
            ?>
```

I realize these errors are checking for simple things right now.  I will make them more complex in the future; ex. looking for '@' in email addresses.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server side scripting language, therefore you wont be able to check the form for errors until it is submitted to the server.

You however have other options for checking the form.

Many people use Javascript to do a pre-check of forms before it is submitted to the server for further PHP checks, you could also do it asynchronously with AJAX(more javascript).

References here for javascript form validation: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

**Javascript**

```
function validateForm(){
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length){
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Note the "onsubmit" in the form field. When the submit button on the form is pressed the function validateForm() is called, if the form has no errors then it submits normally to the PHP backend, if it has errors the user is alerted and the form is not submitted.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So let's say I then use Javascript to check the form.  How would I stop the php script from running (when submit is hit) until javascript makes sure there are no errors?

Comment: I have added edits to my answer, please have a look, it should explain everything you need to know.

Comment: Thanks Aidan, this answer basically covered what I needed although I found a pretty nifty plugin.  Check out [http://jqueryvalidation.org/](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).  It's basically what I wanted.